# Using ng-switch with ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I implemented a page with 3 tabs using ng-switch, which has only one common Save button with ng-disabled attribute, all in one form.

```
        <div id="tab1" ng-switch-default="basic">
        <div id="tab2" ng-switch-when="contact">
        <div id="tab3" ng-switch-when="password">

         <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="save(entity)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine">
            Save
         </button>
```

Problem is ng-disabled performs validation only on the tab which is active, I thinkits because ng-switch **removes** the inactive tab from dom instead of just I **hiding** it. Is there a workaround for ng-switch or should I go back to ng-hide and ng-show?

Comment: Indeed that is what `ngSwitch` does: it removes/adds DOM elements. If you want to just hide/show elements, you need to use `ngShow`/`ngHide`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround I see is to do your validation manually.
I suppose your forms are binded to some model, so you can have your custom validate-function watching directly the model. The `ng-disabled` could be something like:

```
<button
    type="button"
    ng-click="save(entity)"
    ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine || myCustomValidate(entity)">
    Save
</button>
```

That's the only alternative to `ng-hide`/`ng-show` I can think of (right now at least).

Comment: I ended up using ng-hide and ng-show, but I will accept your answer. Thanks to you and @ExpertSystem.